# Conditional Statement In Visualforce?

Tags: if-statement, salesforce, conditional-statements, visualforce

I'm trying to display records on a page (not a form) via VisualForce based on a checkbox value.

For example, if checkbox "Active_c" is checked, I would like to display five subsequent fields.  If checkbox "Active_c" is not checked, I would like to display nothing.

The only example I can find are display text in the output, however, they don't support displaying multiple field output.  For example:

```
{! IF ( CONTAINS('salesforce.com','force.com'), 'Yep', 'Nah') }
```

Anyone have experience with a conditional?

Comment: Can you provide more details. I don't get what you have and where do you have.

Answer (score 1):

Apex Controller:

```salesforce
public YourObject__c YourObject { get; set; }

public YourClass(){
    YourObject = [ Select Active__c, Field1__c, Field2__c From YourObject__c Limit 1 ];
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```salesforce
<apex:actionFunction name="showHideFields" reRender="myFields" />

<apex:inputField value="{!YourObject.Active_c}" onChange="showHideFields()"/>

<apex:outputPanel id="myFields">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!YourObject.Active_c}">
        <apex:outputField value="YourObject.Field1__c" />
        <apex:outputField value="YourObject.Field2__c" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Another example. Without reRendering, just checking the value of the checkbox on the runtime:

```salesforce
<apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputField value="YourObject.Field1__c" rendered="{!YourObject.Active_c}" />
    <apex:outputField value="YourObject.Field2__c" rendered="{!YourObject.Active_c}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Sicco, thanks for the help.  Trying to run this in a VisualForce Email, and I can't seem to get it to work.  

I tried the second option (without reRendering), but it threw the following error: "Error occurred trying to load the template for preview: value for <apex:outputField> is not a dynamic binding!. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem"

As per the first option, where do I set the Apex Controller?  I'm new to VF. Many apologies.

Comment: Can you post your visualforce page or some code snippets here?

Comment: Hey Sicco I was curious to know if it is possible to put a boolean field from the VisualForce page's controller in the rendered section and have it run off that. I am currently getting an error when I try to do it, but am not sure if that is the case.